# How to download older versions from Google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded new application to google play last month, and my system still detecting installs for older versions. i didn't succeed to know how this happened !
any one went through the same situation !

I didn't know where i should ask this question, as google doesn't provide support to apps on google play, if any one know where is the suitable place please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Is your version code updated? Or do you detect new AND old installs?

Comment: @cherry-wave thank you for your comment. i detecting both. the majority is for downloading the new version

Comment: Aurora Store provides this ability. It requires a version ID, however, which isn't exposed to the user unless the user has the foresight to save the commit number of the desired version of the package from Aurora Store's GUI beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

> How to download older versions from Google play?

This is not possible.

There can only be 1 version of your app in the app store at a given time. This includes alpha, beta and production apks. You can not have a alpha and a production apk in the store for example.

> still detecting installs for older versions

The play store keeps track of how many users are running which version of your app. If users don't update the app, the play store will show that they are running an old version, even if you updated your app.

Comment: Yeah that was my first thought too but he is obviously talking of installs (for me this is the installation process) of the older version which is very strange

Comment: @cherry-wave it's not possible. At least not via the google play store. Perhaps users are using a 3rd party store that archives apks

Comment: Or the OP meant running installations by "installs" That would be possible. Could be a user like me who disables auto update.

Comment: @cherry-wave that is what I addressed in my answer. It makes the most sense to me

Comment: thank you for your answer. my system detecting users who open an old versions for the first time. i had a beta application but it's for another version . i have investigated and check it but i didn't succeed to understand what's going on.

Comment: @david sounds like those users had an old version and didn't use it until now, is that possible?

Comment: that's possible , but why some one had downloaded the application before one month and just open it today ! it's very weird . Thanks again

Comment: @david I don't know. But the play store distributing multiple versions of your app is even weirder :-)

Answer (score -1):

**build.gradle>defaultConfig**

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

**manifest.xml**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package.name"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
```

After store will recognize you new version..

Answer (score -1):

Say for example.., if your app has 10 versions. if 10th version is the latest(current) version. If there is any change in the manifest permission changes in old version and to the current version.., In such case your app will install older version in some mobiles. In detail, for ex: till 8th version, if you might have not included mandatory feature like front camera is compulsory for using your app and from 9th version you have mandatory features. Then if the mobile doesn't have front camera will download older version.

Note: The above example mentioned is assumption, find out what your code has major changes in version wise.